# Unable to display parent table with child table in a for loop with template tagging in Django

Tags: django

I want to display an unordered list of NBA teams from my teams table database. Within each team, I want an ordered list of players on that team. So basically I want to produce a list of all objects from my parent table and for each object from the parent table I want a list of all objects from the child table related the parent table. I understand that the problem is methods are not allowed in template tagging, so 'team.players_set.all()' would not be allowed. How else can I get the results that I want?

```
class Teams(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    num_of_plyrs = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} have {self.num_of_plyrs} players."

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Teams"

class Players(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} plays for {self.team}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Players'
__________________________________________________________________________________

def teams(request):
teams = Teams.objects.all()
context = {'teams': teams}
return render(request, 'one_app/teams.html', context)
__________________________________________________________________________________

<h3>NBA Teams</h3>
<ul>
  {% for team in teams %}   
    <li>
  <p>Team: {{ team.name }}</p>
  <p>Number of players: {{ team.num_of_plyrs }}</p>
  <ol>
  {% for plyr in team.players_set.all() %}
    <li>{{ plyr.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>
</li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>There are no teams listed.</li>   
  {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

Comment: Check mptt models, I think it will solve your problem easily.

Comment: this is not reflexive relationship, mptt is not needed

Answer (score 1):

```
  {% for player in team.players_set.all %}
```

---

- table name should be singular
- you can set related_name and use `players` instead `players_set`

  ```
  team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, related_name='players',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ```
- make use of [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve this is:

```
class PlayersView(ListView):
    model = Team
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        teams = []
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        for team in queryset:
             players = team.player_set.all()
             for player in players:
                 teams.append([team, (player.name, ...)]
        return teams
```

And in your template:

```
 {% for team, players in teams %}
     ...
     {% for player in players %}
           ...
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

If you know this is something you might be using a lot and to simplify your view, you can also create a manager:

```
from your_app.managers import TeamManager 

class Team(models.Model):
     ...

     objects = Manager()
     team_manager = managers.TeamManager.as_manager()

     ...
```

In a file manager.py or anything you want:

```
 from django.db.models import QuerySet

 class TeamManager(QuerySet):
     def table_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.all()
        teams = []
        for team in queryset:
             players = team.player_set.all()
             for player in players:
                 teams.append([team, (player.name, ...)]
        return teams
```

And then in your view:

```
class PlayersView(ListView):
    model = Team
    queryset = Team.player_manager.table_queryset()
```